# Urlgenerator error after clearing cache in my lumen api project using nilportugues/laravel5-jsonapi

Tags: laravel, lumen, json-api

But after clearing cache on my lumen api project, and after implementing JWT, I get this error

`FatalThrowableError in Laravel52Provider.php line 59: Type error: Argument 1 passed to NilPortugues\Laravel5\JsonApi\Providers\Laravel52Provider::getRouterCollection() must be an instance of Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator, instance of Laravel\Lumen\Routing\UrlGenerator given, called in /home/vagrant/edu-api/vendor/nilportugues/laravel5-json-api/src/NilPortugues/Laravel5/JsonApi/Providers/Laravel52Provider.php on line 41`

Im hacking at it, but I cant see whats going on or why it worked in the first place. If anyone has some ideas how to track this down, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what got mucked up, but in a last ditch effort, I deleted the vendor directory and did a full `composer update`. works perfectly now. Should have tried that earlier.